# Laravel 5.5 config() not showing data

Tags: php, laravel

I'am working on a old project in laravel 5.5. It going file till date. But now I am configuring Laravel Socialite, added all the provider credentials to services.php. But when redirecting to provider, system throws an error, `formatRedirectUrl() must be of the type array, null given`.

So I checked if the providers are set correctly. To check that I used `config('services.facebook.client_id')`, but it returns nothing.

Note:

- I have tried clearing cache: `php artisan config:clear`
- Caching again: `php artisan config:cache`
- Tried `config('app.name')` which is returning app name as expected.

Any idea what's the reason of this unexpected behaviour?

services.php:

```
<?php

return [
    /*
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      | Third Party Services
      |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      |
      | This file is for storing the credentials for third party services such
      | as Stripe, Mailgun, SparkPost and others. This file provides a sane
      | default location for this type of information, allowing packages
      | to have a conventional place to find your various credentials.
      |
     */

    'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('CALLBACK_URL_FACEBOOK'),
    ],
    'google' => [
        'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('CALLBACK_URL_GOOGLE'),
    ],
    'twitter' => [
        'client_id' => env('TWITTER_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('CALLBACK_URL_TWITTER'),
    ],
];
```

Comment: Can you include structure of the services.php config file in your question?

Comment: added services.php structure

Comment: Might be a silly question, but did you add `FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID` in your `.env` file? You don't have default value set in your config, so if you didn't set it, that's why you are getting empty value.

Comment: they are all there in.env, it gives me nothing whether I set a default value or remove ```env()``` and use only the value.

Comment: Hm, strange. I just replicated the same exact structure, and added `FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID` to my .env , and I got a result, even without clearing cache. If you're still in local development, try to restart your `apache`, or if you're using `php artisan serve`, restart that as well.

Comment: I already tried restarting multiple time. One more thing, if I add another array in the ```services.php```, and try to get the arrays using ```php artisan tinker``` > ```config('services')```, the results are terrible. The order of the arrays are different, and new array also missing.

Comment: Really strange issue, I also used tinker to display this data, and it looked fine. Maybe there's a typo in your .env file (spaces, emtpy strings, invalid characters), that's all that I can think of at the moment.

Comment: checked env file multiples time, that's okay. I can access the data using env() method.